# Unix command or bash script to convert file with abc.def to abc-def-1.0.0.tar.gz?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I would think it would use sed, regex for the substitution and to select the next line's version and append, etc.

input file

```
name: abc.def
version: 1.0.0
```

output file

```
name: abc-def-1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat file
name: abc.def
version: 1.0.0
```

You can create a variable with `awk` containing the version number and replace it within a `sed` command in a `for loop`

```sh
for f in file; do
    ver=$(awk '/version/ {print $2}' $f); 
    sed -Ei "/name/ {s/(\S+)\.(\S+)/\1-\2-$ver.tar.gz/}" $f;
done
```

```
cat file
name: abc-def-1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, given your input file something like this should do it.

---

The script named `script.ed` (name it to your own hearts content)

```
2t.
2s/^version: *//
s/$/.tar.gz/
1s/$/-/
s/\./-/
.,2j
%p
Q
```

---

Then run it against the file. Assuming the file name is `file.txt`

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if you're satisfied with the output or if *in-place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `%p` to silence the output.

---

A short explanation. Running the commands one-by-one/line-by-line except for `%p` and `Q`.

`2t.` means copy or duplicate line 2 in the file. The output is:

```
name: abc.def
version: 1.0.0
version: 1.0.0
```

---

`2s/^version: *//` Remove the leading string `version:` and any amount of space after it from line 2. The output is:

```
name: abc.def
1.0.0
version: 1.0.0
```

---

`s/$/.tar.gz/` at the same line buffer which is line 2 in the file in question. Add the string `.tar.gz` at the end. The output is:

```
name: abc.def
1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

---

`1s/$/-/` at line 1 of the file add a trailing dash `-`. Output is:

```
name: abc.def-
1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

---

`s/\./-` at the same line (line 1) replace/change the dot `.` into a dash `-`. Output is:

```
name: abc-def-
1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

---

`.,2j` at the same line (line 1) the dot `.` represents the current line, and line `2` join them together. The `j` command does that. The final output is:

```
name: abc-def-1.0.0.tar.gz
version: 1.0.0
```

---

See:

- [GNU ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- [POSIX ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)
- [ed](http://sdf.lonestar.org/index.cgi?tutorials/ed)
- [ed in pdf](https://wolfram.schneider.org/bsd/7thEdManVol2/edtut/edtut.pdf)
- [MirBSD ed](http://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/ed.htm)
- [bash hackers wiki ed](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed)

Also your local man pages.

`man 1p ed`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i.bak -lne 'if (/name: (.*)/) { ($name = $1) =~ y/./-/ } elsif (/version: (.*)/) { 
    $version = $1; print "name: $name-$version.tar.gz\n$_" } else { print }' infiles
```